# Regexp separate two words

Tags: regex

I need to capture such string as a TWO separate matches:

```
MLB m L B
```

So output should be two matches:

```
1. MLB 
2. m L B
```

There maybe any or zero characters  between earch of three letters in match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So one match always has three characters that may be whitespace-separated?

```
(?:\w\s*){3}
```

matches `MLB` or `m L M` in your example.

To match precisely those letters, use

```
M\s*L\s*B
```

and activate the case-insensitive option of your regex implementation.

To allow any character between the letters:

```
M.*L.*B
```

(and you can't get any more basic than that in regex - you'll want to [read a regex tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info))

Comment: Sorry maybe I was bit incorrect, I need to pass these three letters as input variables! So I need to match exactly these letters: M,L,B. So I need to capture sequence of exactly these letters.

Comment: Thank you Tim. Can we declare case insetivity in expression? And could you write final expression, because I newbie in this...

Comment: Some engines allow this: `(?i)M\s*L\s*B`.

Comment: But how looks final expression?

Comment: That *is* the final expression.

Comment: It doesnt capture if there is other letter between M L B, for expamle M a LB

Comment: Then you should have taken greater care in specifying your problem. Also, you get more help if you start accepting answers to your previously answered questions (makes people more likely to help if they can expect some appreciation in return).

Comment: Some additional conditions to this regexp. For example, in this expression i should hightlight: 

> M **m L B**  a d  **m a L a B**

Comment: How would the regex know that it should match the second, but not the first "m"? What's the rule here?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a string like `MLB m L B`, then this should work

```
(\w*)(\s+)(.*)
```